# Remove delete button from approval window

Tags: sharepoint

When tasks get assigned to approver, approver sees delete button on top of the window , how to hide that button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SharePoint Designer to edit the workflow and also modify the approval window with Info Path Designer.

See [this example](http://web.archive.org/web/20121226191852/http://www.jasperoosterveld.com/2012/05/how-to-change-workflow-task-form-with.html)